# IE7 position absolute divs (popover) :: popover div not displaying properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-7

I am trying to display a popover divs [here](http://staging.serviceportal.com.au/service05/plush_form.do)  . Please click the question mark icons. You will notice that there is a popover div that shows up in all browsers. However, in Internet Explorer 7, it fails to display properly. I tried using z-index property but that does not seem to work. How can I make the popover show up on top of the input field?

Below is a sample HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-5 divPopUp">
<label class="control-label customerAccountNo" for="custom4">Customer Acct No</label>
<img src="32005/images/iconQuestion.png" alt="Help" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="Found on the Plush Rewards flyer provided at the store. Lost this? Please contact the store you purchased from" class="popUp customerAccountNoImg"/> </div>
```

Screenshot added of the issue:

[image: Please notice that the popover div is hidden behind the input]

Comment: pls add screenshots instead of a link to a website that will be invalid in probably a couple of days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not easy to solve without a fiddle, but using IE debug tool, I was able to solve the problem, but not sure it really works in live exemple.

I added a z-index in the div col-xs-5 :

```
<div class="col-xs-5 divPopUp" style="z-index: 100">
```

Can you edit css for this element ?